# We need more focus for a close-vote "Need more focus"

Tags: discussion

I almost clicked "Need more focus" option (as someone else already) for a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61273728/1997232) which just need more details. I suspect there are more similar missclicks since that change.

Before it was like this

[image]

I was referring to those as "unclear" (add more) and "too broad" (add less). Was very clear.

And now

[image]

Somehow those both choices are just "Needs more" to me. I need *more focus* to figure out which one is which.

Maybe it's just old habbit and after a while I will get used to a new spellings. Maybe it's word "focus" which is not telling. "You need more focus ... to add more details" - that's how I read it.

Just wanted to rise up the topic.

Comment: It'll change again soon as the 'welcoming' tinkering continues.  If a question needs closing, just click on one of the buttons and then OK.

Comment: I actually see a difference between those choices (albeit somewhat slight). The first one, Needs details or clarity, is the former unclear. The 2nd choice, Needs more focus, is the former too broad. Sure they both "Needs more" but the more are different things.

Comment: Mentally replace the word "focus" with the word "less". "Needs more less" pretty much sums up what the question needs :).

Comment: also need more information for debugging should be mentioned in that Listing