# Question Close Updates: Phase 1

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, closed-questions, announcement

This week we rolled out a series of changes to [improve parts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394871/upcoming-feature-new-question-close-experience) of the question close workflow.  Below are the changes and impacted sites.

#### Close & Flag screen updates

This change is live on Stack Overflow, international sites, and across the network. These updates are copy changes that aim to more accurately represent close reasons and reframes close flags more constructively. This update includes:

- General styling improvements to all close screens (e.g. flag screen, mod close screen).
- [Renamed “off-topic” close reason to “A community-specific reason”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396592/goodbye-off-topic-hello-community-specific-reasons/396597#396597) on the primary close-reasons page. This addresses the pain point that many closed questions tagged as “off-topic” aren’t in fact off-topic.

[image]

- Renamed title of ‘off-topic’ screen to ‘Why isn’t this question suited for [Community]?’’

[image]

- Renamed  ‘should be closed’ option to ‘needs improvement’ on the primary flag screen, focusing the language on the 'why' vs. 'what' behind the flag.

[image]

- Renamed the title on ‘Should be closed’ screen to  ‘Why should this be closed?’ and updated ‘off-topic’ within this screen to ‘A community-specific reason’

[image]

- Styling improvements to “Manage [Community] specific close-reasons” (previously called “Manage off-topic close reasons”) screen for mods and the ability to define the post notice content so that it matches close reason more specifically, rather than being generic text.

Big thanks to SO/SE mods for feedback on renaming here.

#### Improved closed question editor

This change is live on Stack Overflow and International sites now and will roll out to network sites once we’ve resolved any glaring issues. This update borrows UI patterns from the new Ask a Question flow. The goal is to provide a richer, guided experience for users editing questions that are closed.

Post authors will know why their question was closed along with tips on how to improve it.

*Tips modal example*

[image]

From there, users will see a similar editor and review step to the question flow experience where guidance is provided in the right rail.

*Closed question editor example*

[image]

#### Email and Inbox notifications for closed questions

This is launching on Monday (April 20) on Stack Overflow as an A/B test. This update sends question authors an inbox notification when their question is closed. The idea is that the inbox notification will guide users to their closed question and the post notice displayed there will encourage them to edit the question to improve it.

If there are no edits, the question remains closed, and hasn't been deleted within an hour of closure, we'll also send a follow-up email with guidance about what to do next.

It’s running as an A/B test so that we can measure how effective these notifications are in guiding users to edit their questions.

(**Update:** The experiment has finished, and the closed post inbox notification has graduated and is live on all sites. There is now a new experiment that is live testing how effective the email is. [Read more about it in the official announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356742/question-closed-notifications-experiment-results-and-graduation).)

*Inbox notification example*

[image]

*Email example*

[image]

There has already been some feedback around naming updates, thank you. We've flagged those and are reviewing them. Let us know if you have more feedback or questions.

Comment: Thanks for the announcement, Des! Please pass on the following to whomever it may concern: this kind of announcement about a major feature change really needs to be posted *before* the change is made, not a week after. Preferably it would be posted as a joint announcement and request for feedback, so that the hundreds of people using these features every day can provide input/improvement recommendations before the change goes live.

Comment: @TylerH appreciate that and agree. I take responsibility for the delay here. Going forward we'll make sure it goes out the same time as the update.

Comment: This all looks great, I love how you incorporated the ability of moderators to be more involved with the close reasons and refined the wording of "off topic". In my opinion, the [set of close reasons and the wording surrounding it is/was outdated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394871/upcoming-feature-new-question-close-experience/396018#396018), and this makes great strides towards modernizing that, also helps ensure it stays up to date.

Comment: I offered some [general thoughts on the flag window on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346483/flag-window-redux-proposed-syntax)

Comment: "Going forward we'll make sure it goes out **the same time** as the update."  Going out at the same time does not allow people to become aware of it early and expect it.  They will still be in reactive mode when things suddenly change.  Going out before the change gives users the chance to be ready for it.

Comment: Is it possible to Know whether the question or answer has an existing flag (like the close(2) count) ?

Comment: @Taplar I think that's reasonable, whenever possible. I'll take this feedback back to our team. Sharing things on meta earlier, in general, is something we're actively working on.

Comment: @Des, when posting an announcement for changes that are rolled out network-wide, could you make that announcement (also?) in [meta.se]? As I don't frequently visit SO, but do use other network sites regularly, it was only by accident that I stumbled upon this announcement.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I did post on MSE [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346638/question-close-updates). let me know if you feel that wasn't sufficient. Thanks!

Comment: @Des, thanks. I now remember seeing that post, but I guess it didn't register enough with me to be able to find it back after a few days.

Comment: At this point I don't even understand what to choose when voting for closure anymore. I pick something, but after voting I feel like that was the wrong thing to pick, and it leaves a bitter taste in my mouth. Please **stop** randomly changing the wording every now and then. Close reasons were already worded pretty badly (IMHO), changing it around to something else that is still bad does not solve anything.

Comment: AFAIK, people asking questions get no indication as to why there are one or two votes to close the question until it is closed, so it doesn't really give them much indication of what they can do to improve their question till it is too late. Seems a bit cruel...

Comment: I think that from one side is a good thing; from the other side, many people could mark as "closeable" right questions for no reason.

Comment: What is the intended distinction between the top level "Needs Details or Clarity" and the Community-specific Stack Overflow "Needs Debugging Details"?

Comment: @TylerV Indeed. We now have "needs focus", "needs details" and "needs debugging details". How this turned out better than "too broad"/"unclear"/"seeking debugging help without providing the code to reproduce", nobody knows. In update #2 all these will all be replaced with "needs stuff".

Answer (score 60):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Please bring the the little blue box around the remaining numbers of flags/votes back. It served so well to focus what is important.

[image: Blue box]

The image is cropped from [a screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBoyQ.png) by [Makyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3773011)

Comment: I think the removal is probably a consistency improvement; the blue box around existing votes is more important to let you know others have cast a vote. The blue box around remaining votes or flags is thus confusing because it can make a user think there are 100 other votes or flags. Also, the important thing isn't really how many votes/flags you have left, but whether there are already any on the post.

Comment: @TylerH I see your point. However, there are really a lot of users <3K. The blue box will be nice for all of them. There's also nothing to suggest that one blue box will eliminate any of the others :) I say: Lets have them all. They could even be colour-coded, making it a little colour box request.

Comment: I don't think the blue box adds any value even for sub-3K users. You have to read the grey text on both sides of the box to understand what the blue box number means anyway, at which point there's not any value in having a blue box around part of it.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. It was easier to focus and go to straight to the number before. Now I have to read the entire sentence every time.

Comment: Once you have read the sentence once, you shouldn't need to read it again (unless you forget what the number means). Beyond that, I'm not seeing why you need to 'focus' so much on how many flags you have left. Flag content while you have flags; when you don't have any, you won't be able to anyway.

Comment: @TylerH It is not about reading it is about finding the part you want to read. With blue box you could just read the information in split second. Without it you need to scan the sentence to find where number begins.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar That doesn't require a bright blue box, though. Even just making the numeral **bold** would draw the eye.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I think Tyler's point was... you don't even *really* need to know how many flags you have left *at all*. Flag while you can, stop when you can't

Comment: @Catija That's true. But the box is cute :)   (Typo fixed)

Comment: @Nick I understand that from the PoV of someone who rarely uses up all of their flags... for people with only a handful of flags, though... I know that rationing them towards the end of the day is a thing they feel is necessary... to save the last few flags for blatantly problematic things like rude or abusive content or spam.

Comment: How is this related?

Comment: @S.S.Anne The recent change to the dialog included removal of the blue box.

Answer (score 53):

To me, the meaning of **"Needs more focus"** is rather different from the explanatory text "*The question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.*"
If the point of that option is to state that there are too many questions, then the bold text could make that clearer at first glance - something like

> **Asks multiple questions**
>  <sub>The question currently includes multiple questions which would be better asked separately.</sub>

Looking at the explanations, a question that 'needs focus' but doesn't actually contain multiple questions (which is a common problem) should probably instead be marked as "Needs details or clarity".

---

EDIT: from one of the comments below, apparently "Needs focus" is basically supposed to mean the same thing as "too broad". In that case, the problem is with the "The question currently includes multiple questions in one" explanatory text. It's very common for something that's a single question to still be too broad. If someone asks "How do I make a website?", that's not multiple questions, but it is too broad. (It might still be fair to say that it *could be split* into multiple questions, but not that it *currently includes multiple questions in one*).

Comment: *indeed, unfocused posts sometimes don't contain any clear questions* - Then, would they not, instead be "needs detail or clarity"? I agree that having multiple questions isn't the sole reason for needing focus. The old close reason used to speak of questions that were broad enough to be the subject of entire books rather than something that was answerable in a few hundred or thousand characters.

Comment: Needs more focus simply needs to be removed (expansion on that [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396018/1026459)). All that is really required for focus is detail, which is outlined in other places. We should be encouraging posts which generate multiple answers, however not those which ask multiple separate questions. I agree that Asks multiple questions is a good suggestion here, given that "Needs more focus" is removed entirely.

Comment: An alternative example for "Asks multiple questions" could be ""Asks too many disparate questions": Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. Edit this to remove questions which can be asked in their own post."

Comment: @Catija - They would need details or clarity, depending on the situation. [Those should also be two separate close reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396018/1026459). "Add "Needs details": There are not enough details provided to answer this question. Please edit this question with additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Add "Needs clarity": As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Edit the question to clarify your specific problem."

Comment: I think "needs focus" is for things that are "not narrow enough". "Asks too many Questions" is not the same as asking too broad a Question, like "How do I make a website" or "Can I write my own compiler like this".. it doesn't matter if they provide all the details, it's still too broad.

Comment: @Scratte That's a great way of putting what I was trying to say! :D

Comment: Maybe a change of "This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only." to something like "This question is too broad to be practically answerable. It should focus on one problem only.". It needs more tuning though :)

Comment: Answers are allowed to be 30,000 characters in length, so broadness really needs to be tempered here. "How do I make a wesbite" is asking for a process or tutorial... this already covered under the current rule "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more
This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.". Same goes for "can I write my own compiler like this"

Comment: @Scratte you're describing the old Too Broad close reason. Which seemed really appropriate while "Needs Focus" weirdly *itself* needs to be properly focused.

Comment: Really though, the power of the new tool released is that it allows Moderators to take a more active roll here. If there is a need for a reason which explicitly covers situations where someone is asking for advice on their compiler or writing an entire website, that can now be addressed through a [feature-request] or the topic can be raised in a [discussion] and we will actually make progress.

Comment: @Catija *unfocused posts sometimes don't contain any clear questions - "Then, would they not, instead be "needs detail or clarity"?* Maybe, and that's where the confusion is - there are two options where the bold text looks like it means something like "unclear", but when you look at the explanatory text, one of them actually means, specifically, "too many questions".

Comment: @topoReinstateMonica If I'm remembering correctly, the changes to the close reasons were intended as rewordings, not new close reasons. So, they're still "too broad" and "unclear"... just... the phrasing is supposed to emphasize how to fix the problem, not focus on what the problem is... so "split this into more than one question" and "add more details".

Comment: The old explanation of it taking a whole book to answer seemed perfect to me.

Comment: @Catija  - If "needs focus" is supposed to mean "too broad", then the explanatory text "The question currently includes multiple questions" doesn't apply very well in many cases. If someone asks "what were the major developments in music in the second half of the 20th century?", that's definitely not multiple questions, but it probably is too broad.

Comment: Re: these comments, the critical distinction here is that we need two separate close reasons for two separate things: "it's unclear what you are asking" and "your Question<sup>1</sup> is too broad". The latter can and *did* mean **both**: "the question you have asked is not specific or narrow enough to be a good candidate for SO Q&A" and "you have asked too many questions", because... <sup>1</sup> - the *Question* (capitalized) is the *post*, not the/an interrogative phrase somewhere in the body. cc @Catija & Scratte

Comment: please bring "too broad" back !

Comment: @Catija I'm still encountering this issue where a question is too broad in scope (e.g. needs a blog post or book to answer) and none of the prescribed options cover it. "needs more detail" in no way makes a 'too broad in scope' question less broad in scope... A very detailed, very clear question about how to build a site that emulates Facebook's Newsfeed is still textbook "too broad" in scope but neither "needs detail" nor "needs more focus" apply when you look at the descriptions under those reasons.

Comment: @Catija This answer is exactly true. The problem with "needs focus" is not necessarily that too many question are asked — though it _might_ be. It also very well might be that _one_ question is asked but it is way too big, like "How do I write an app like Twitter?" or "How do I implement search in my app?" Now that the explanation says it's too many questions, I am forced to use "needs details" instead, which is wrong too. The explanation needs to express _my_ reasons.

Comment: @Catija Here's a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61806734/how-to-make-a-single-view-animal-management-app There is just one question: but it is "how do I write this entire app?" The text for lacking focus needs to explain what's wrong with that.

Answer (score 29):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

> #### Email and Inbox notifications for closed questions
>
> This is live on Stack Overflow as an A/B test. **This update sends askers an inbox notification** and email (if inbox notification was not viewed) when their question is closed, giving them guidance about what to do next. It’s running as an A/B test so that we can measure how effective these notifications are in guiding users to edit their questions.

Please consider enabling this for followers of questions as well.

Comment: Bonus: consider letting [people opt in and out of it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346515/332043)

Comment: Yes, I would really like this combined with an opt-in regardless of how the A/B test works out. This would allow people to see [updates on their question regardless of age](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258057/216074).

Answer (score 25):

> About general computing hardware and software
>
> This question is more likely to get an answer on Super User.

These closure reasons now sound indistinguishable from the migration path **A community-specific reason** -> **This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network** -> **belongs on superuser.com**. It just says that *this question* belongs elsewhere. The old closure text indicated that the question could be *re-asked* thus might not fit in its current form.

I find that it's now misleading as it sounds like the question could be copy pasted or maybe *should* just be moved. Yet, the reason to pick *this* closure reason rather than the migration path is because the question most likely wouldn't be a good fit *in its current form* on Super User. It can be posted again but following the standards of the other site.

> About professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration
>
> This question is more likely to get an answer on Server Fault.

Same thing but there is no migration path to Server Fault. Yet this closure reason *sounds like one*.

I don't know what guidance would question authors be given if their post is closed using one of the above two reasons but it *must* emphasise that if re-asking on another stack, they should check the help centre and make sure the question fits.

Other than the guidance to authors, the guidance to *close voters* can be misleading. I assume that the closure reason is the same as before but I really cannot say - maybe there was a change in how this works? Even if there *wasn't* a change then, how is somebody who sees this dialog for the first time to understand what the difference between these close reasons and the migrations is?

Comment: FWIW I think it has always been silly to have two close reasons for the purpose of saying "this question belongs on Super User". While only one is an actual migration attempt to Super User, the other one basically says "ask this on super user instead". It's especially silly when we still don't have migration options to Software Engineering or Code Review but we have close reasons for Super User and a migration option for LaTeX.

Comment: @TylerH I don't necessarily disagree. I do, however, only compare it to the previous version - now it's more unclear than before. But yes, if we have one closure reason that says "should be on Super User", we likely don't need a migration path. Or vice versa - if we have a migration path, we don't need a "please re-post this on Super User". Also, I wouldn't like a migration path for CR, since there are way too many suggestions that a question belongs there, when it's actually not a good fit. Having an automatic migration would mean just passing a hot potato around.

Comment: Indeed I would prefer the 'ask' wizard/experience kick a user over to CR *during the asking process* rather than either of us having to worry about migrating/migrated content.

Comment: I've kinda wondered this myself. The explanation I could come up with is that something being off topic and valid for SF or SU doesn't mean the question is in good enough shape to migrate. That said, this isn't really related to the changes we've made... these close reasons existed long before this. If you want to have a discussion of migration paths or community-specific close reasons, they are up to the community to decide with the exception that there's a limit of how many of each are allowed.

Comment: Also worth remembering that migration paths are considered from both ends. If a migration path to SF is churning up too much junk, it might get shut down to avoid that. Some helpful pages (10k) - https://stackoverflow.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats and https://stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats (which is currently broken but we're trying to figure out what died).

Answer (score 22):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Unless it was actually intended to change how/when this should be used, please change the following option:

> ***Not reproducible* or was caused by a typo**

..into something like:

> ***No longer reproducible* or was caused by a typo**

Otherwise, its (inferred) use cases will overlap with **"Needs debugging details"** in many situations.

I believe my suggestion above is still concise enough and preserves the meaning of the original message which used to be:

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced
>   or a simple typographical error**

Comment: was going to post the same. "Not reproducible" is too generic and would fit for 99% of questions that lack information.

Answer (score 20):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The conjunctions used on the community close reasons are inconsistent:

[image]

Posting my other post here: [Inconsistent conjunctions with new community close reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396633/inconsistent-conjunctions-with-new-community-close-reasons)

I have other thoughts over there too.

Comment: They're not "inconsistent"; they mean different things.

Comment: I agree the first one should be an "or". The third one should probably just be "etc."

Comment: @SteveBennett And "etc." is short for "et cetera", which is Latin for... "and the rest" or, more colloquially, "and more" :)

Comment: Yup, two things that are literally synonymous are not necessarily interchangeable. Like the classic butt-dial vs booty-call etc.

Comment: @AndrewCheong it’s a change of what was there. The or is more specific to avoid the ambiguity

Answer (score 15):

#### Clicking "needs improvement" leads to "Why should this question be closed?"?

I'm not sure whether this is intended or not, but I would not ask someone "why do you think it should be closed?" as a response to someone saying "I think this question needs improvement".

A better wording would be

> Why does this question need improvement?

Comment: I made a local change to the dialog so it now says "needs improvement (should be closed) ..." just so I don't get confused :)

Comment: Apparently, when you have the "Cast close and reopen votes" privilege, clicking **"needs improvement"** redirects you to the VTC dialog (which makes sense, I guess?) because your flag will be converted to a close-vote anyway. If you don't have that privilege, the title of the dialog says **"What kind of improvement does this question need?"** instead (tested on SuperUser). Here's a [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/TgRvFTU.png).

Comment: Yeah - going from "needs improvement" to "Why ... closed?" is an implicit (Freudian?) admission that closing a question is actually an improvement!

Answer (score 15):

Please put the big blue action button at the lower *right* of the dialog, not the lower left.

That is the universal convention. Lower left basically hides the button, as no one looks there. It runs counter to convention, expectation, and muscle memory.

(Otherwise I’m greatly enjoying the new wording and look.)

Comment: I have a [feature-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396585/please-move-the-flag-button-back-to-the-right-side) for that. It contains a few workarounds.

Comment: @Scratte Cool thanks, I’d raised this in a comment but didn’t see it gaining any traction. Upvoted your post.

Answer (score 14):

Please do announce (post like this on meta) **before** making it into production.

---

Since it went into production before announce I've already asked [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396745/1997232) (now closed as duplicate, because here is already [a post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396761/1997232) with solution to the problem I've faced).

Comment: But your phrasing 'I was referring to those as "unclear" (add more) and "too broad" (add less). Was very clear.' captures the two choices very well.

Answer (score 12):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

How about renaming the "needs improvement" flag?

The current name is simply untrue for a number of questions that need to be closed. No amount of improvement is going to turn "What's your favourite programming joke", or a question that belongs on another site, into an appropriate question.

My suggestion might be **"not a good fit"**. **"Not suited for [Community]"** could also be a consideration. Based on new the close dialog phrasing, this only matches the phrasing of a subset of the close reasons, but in reality it could apply to the other reasons too. If we make it roughly match the close dialog title (which is arguably the most logical approach), that would mean making it **"should be closed"** or changing the close dialog title.

The description can largely stay the same, apart from a minor addition for the above.

Comment: I agree that “needs improvement” is a bad label, but the problem it intended to solve was to make the label _actionable_. “off-topic” or “not suited for ⟨community⟩” aren’t really actionable. “off-topic” and “needs improvement” are both misleading. So what is a _correct **and** actionable_ label?

Comment: @user4642212 "*should be closed*" sounds nice.

Comment: @TylerH I was thinking more along the lines of “actionable for the asker”. Semantically, the different reasons are split into “needs improvement” (e.g. unclear, needs details, asking multiple questions, etc.), which is actionable for anyone (especially the asker), and “should be closed” (e.g. caused by typo, blatantly off-topic, etc.), which isn’t actionable for the asker (which is correct). But I’m not sure two such categories in the close vote dialog would be feasible.

Comment: @user4642212 Was the change intended to make it actionable? The applicable part of the question says "focusing the language on the 'why'", which this does as well. But, either way, the phrasing *can't* be correct and actionable (unless you add an "or" to make it *partially* actionable), because it's *not* always actionable. The explanation given to the post author, on the other hand, should of course be actionable (if at all possible).

Comment: @TylerH Then again, there may not be a label that is actionable for everyone for every reason, so “should be closed” is probably still the best way to go. It’s always correct, it’s always actionable for reviewers, and question owners probably get specific guidance anyway. That’s also basically what the last comment of Dukeling says—I just didn’t fully read it yet.

Answer (score 7):

#### "This question belongs on another Stack Exchange Site"

Taking this option does not seem provide an obvious means of selecting a site more suited to the question - there are five radio buttons to choose from and a close question button to confirm your choice.

Are there reasons as to why one should be able to vote to close a question as belonging on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) as opposed to say, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) or [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251652/flagging-migration-should-include-more-options9), for example. And many questions [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migration?tab=Frequent).

Comment: Worth noting this was the logical path for questions not in English, but the correct handling is mark as "Needs more details or clarity" according to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content ... confusing.

Answer (score 7):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Make comment section at **"A community-specific reason"** → **"Other - add a comment"** resizable.

For now this area allows us to see two lines which sometimes is not enough.

[image: cystom close reason]

Can we add an option to resize it like in standard comment sections?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Still disagree with the whole emailing people thing. But I hope it works out for you and you accomplish what you wish to with it. Perhaps the A/B test will prove effective, and I will be wrong.

Otherwise, I have nothing negative to say about this.

Comment: To note, "This update sends askers an inbox notification and email (if inbox notification was not viewed) when their question is closed, giving them guidance about what to do next.", indicates that the email is only sent out when the inbox notification goes unnoticed. Moreover, there is a setting in your profile that you can disable inbox emails, which should prevent these. If a user doesn't want emails, then it seems like it is rather easy for them to avoid them.

Comment: @TravisJ Just FYI - I made an edit to clarify how the inbox/email thing works. We're definitely mindful of not sending unnecessary emails, and we'll be reviewing both the data and the feedback we get otherwise.

Comment: @AdamLear Awesome. To be fair, this isn't really a criticism as much as it is a disagreement. As long as you don't send me unnecessary emails (which you seem to understand and agree with me on that), I'm fine. I certainly wish the effort the best and will be perfectly fine if you find this is effective and go through with it anyway. As long as I'm heard (which I feel I totally am, btw).

Comment: @AdamLear Is there already an option to disable emails? If so, where is it?

Comment: @S.S.Anne All email settings are in the user profile under [Settings -> Edit email settings](/users/email/settings/current). This particular email will be in the "Tips & Reminders" category.

Answer (score 3):

[feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request)

There now is a tooltip that explains that an automated comment is posted on the question when someone votes to close a question with a custom off-topic reason.

The other instance when an automated comment is placed on a question is when someone votes to close a question as a duplicate. Can a similar tooltip be placed there?

There are regularly questions about this behaviour, which I can't find right now ofcourse :).

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if this tooltip on the duplicate closure also mentioned that it will be in the form of a question to the OP, because that has yet to cease annoying me.

Answer (score -2):

What should happen when a question has 1 or 2 close votes, then gets edited to conform to the site guidelines?

I found that the number of close votes still remains displayed under the question, which may attract more close votes (the [goal distance](https://samueljwoods.com/30-principles-pre-suasion-robert-cialdini-conversions/) is only 1), even though the initial ones were for an old version of the question.

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61305578/what-typescript-configuration-produces-output-closest-to-node-js-14-capabilities).

Comment: I feel like this doesn't belong here, since there is no change in how things work. Yes, close votes remain even after an edit is made. People who voted *can* retract their votes, if they so wish but they have to see the edit and react to it, it's not automatic. I've found it *sometimes* make sense to have a "counter vote" to say "this has votes for closure but actually shouldn't be closed" but admittedly, it's quite rare and I'm not sure I'd want a full site feature for that.

Comment: The opinion based close reason is used incorrectly like 90% of the time, your example is one of them. Nothing should happen to close votes after edits, because the system works based on voting how you encounter content. That said, even as first asked, there was no need to close this question. Questions of this type are almost always answered by professionals, experts, or language authors, yet for some reason they are called "opinions". It isn't an opinion when Eric Lippert writes a response to how something was made for C#, yet we close those now. It needs to change.

Comment: @TravisJ: I'm skeptic that those power-trippers who vote to close questions, will ever change their ways, but - do you see any practical way to make this change?

Comment: @DanDascalescu - Something to keep in mind, these people for the most part are just strict enforcers. They mean well. So, it is the rules you must adjust, not their behavior. As such, we need to simply remove the opinion based close reason. [It was put in place as part of a plan to replace a close reason which prevented extended discussion, polling, arguments, and debate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171732/help-us-make-not-constructive-and-not-a-real-question-closures-more-effectiv). However, "opinion based" goes too far.

Comment: "Opinionated needs to be fully remodeled. We want material which is based on specific expertise, however, often posts are closed which include any level of opinion. This unfortunate situation has grown to the point where good subjective questions no longer even show up due to the knee jerk reaction of the "jackbooted heel of justice". -https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396018/1026459