# Why close this question that just needs clarification?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I'm looking at a question: [What will be the pattern for UTF-8 in Json Schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61615172/what-will-be-the-pattern-for-utf-8-in-json-schema)

It seems on-topic for the site, appears similar to other questions I've answered on the subject matter (both in Unicode, and JSON Schema, of which I am an author), and the question does have a few minor problems; however the problem isn't that the question cannot be answered; the problem is the question seems to mis-use some technical terms, and I can answer this question as soon as we can nail down what was actually intended.

For example, I suspect the question author wants to say "BMP (basic multilingual plane)" but said "UTF-8" instead. However, like a lot of issues, it may require some back-and-forth questioning to understand the true nature.

Questions may be [closed as unclear very quickly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing), so *once the author has provided a clarification, I cannot post an answer.*

So why jump on closing the question? This means that people with an answer cannot add one. This provides a *strong disincentive* to closing a question if I think the author is going to clarify it in a way I can answer.

I think it's fine to mark this as "needs clarification" but I want to *encourage* seeking & getting clarifications from the author, and closing the question outright seems exactly the wrong way to handle this.

I've had a recurring problem with perfectly usable questions being closed. For example, multiple cases where someone adds incorrect tags, then people with expertise in those tags don't understand the question & mark it as spam, when in fact it was just triaged poorly; So I typically have to track down a moderator to get it reopened just so I can answer it, which seems like a poor use of our time. I'd like to know if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: Closing it is to encourage clarification from the author. If answers are flowing in what incentive do they have to add details and clarify it?

Comment: Also answers to unclear posts lead to big messes. (They're not really answers, because an unclear post isn't really a question.) Also please research before considering asking. PS "the problem isn't that the question cannot be answered" vs "I can answer this question as soon as"--contradiction.

Comment: @philipxy I spent a good half-hour looking at similar questions on this site, but I couldn't find any that answer why we're closing questions that are answerable, but merely need clarifications.

Comment: @gnat That's definitely a related question; but if the author offers a clarification, I still have to go out to a moderator to get the question re-opened. This step seems a waste of time.

Comment: @philipxy I see that in some questions, but I don't think it's always a contradiction. Sometimes the question can be answered despite its technical problems. Sometimes the question has no technical problems, there's just multiple ways to do it depending on personal circumstances.
The core of this question is still "how do answer a question that's been clarified"— I can change the title if you think that's a better one.

Comment: You say: "I can answer this question *as soon as we can nail down what was actually intended*." That's *exactly* when a question should be closed. If you can't answer *now* with the information as it is in the question *right now* and need information or clarification from the OP, then the question should be closed until such time as that information or clarification is provided by the OP.

Comment: @Makyen The problem is "... so once the author has provided a clarification, I cannot post an answer."
If I close the question, I can't reopen it once I have a clarification; and I can't post an answer. I have a _disincentive_ to wanting the question closed.

Comment: If it's "been clarified", then it's not unclear, and shouldn't be closed for being unclear. So it's really not clear what you're trying to ask. (If there are multiple answers because the post could be asking multiple questions, the post could be asking multiple questions, so it's not clear.) 'The core of this question is still "how do answer a question that's been clarified"'--that is *not* the question in your title or post. Again, you are not clear. How you answer a closed question is, you wait until it's opened. PS From your lack of clarity here no wonder you differ with closers re "clear".

Comment: "you wait until it's opened"
What this _effectively_ means is I'm just never going to answer the question.

Comment: Re "disincentive"--learn how the site works & follow the rules. What does some unrelated motivation have to do with anything? (Seriously. Non-rhetorical. Again, what is your 1 actual question here you are trying to ask?) PS Yes. You may never answer it. So what? Whether it's clear or not by you, others think it's not clear. Or worse you think it's unclear too but for some reason you somehow want permission to violate protocols, or something, I don't know what. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: @philipxy Well as I noted, I'm an _editor_ on JSON Schema, and I have an incentive to make sure that questions are answered accurately & timely. And I can only assume that Stack Overflow wants the same thing for its audience. (Also, I made _several_ clarifying edits so far. I always update the question with updates from the comments.)

Comment: @awwright I don't understand why you wouldn't answer/want to answer a question once it's re-opened if you want to answer it while it is closed, assuming it's the same question.

Comment: @TylerH I do want to answer a question once it's re-opened; but what's _more likely_ is we simply forget about it; or it gets answered in days instead of minutes.

Comment: @awwright While I can understand that you think you have a disincentive to have the question closed when it's unclear, you actually have an incentive for it to be closed. If it's unclear and open, it's more likely to then be closed and, if the OP doesn't clarify, deleted. If you've put out effort to answer it, then that effort has gone to waste once the question is deleted. In addition, once the question is answered, the OP is *far* less likely to provide the necessary clarification. So, you're better of spending time answering clear questions which won't be closed and, potentially, deleted.

Comment: @awwright I think an answer in a few days is a *great* outcome for a free resource from strangers... would that all askers are so lucky. Second, if you are actually invested in it then you will be checking back on it every so often to see its status and can vote or flag it to be reopened. If it fails due to aging away (there are so many questions on SO that this happens a lot), you can re-flag/re-vote and try again. Worst case, have OP copy the contents, delete the closed post, and create a new post with the new, improved contents so that the new question won't get closed.

Comment: @TylerH For some things sure, but the alternative for us is using realtime chat—slightly less organized, but realtime answers. And that's just _a lot_ of things that aren't obvious. When I'm answering questions here, I get a feed of questions in my subject areas, and I'm willing to answer them right away—this is one of the reasons we can point to Stack Overflow. And it's much easier to contribute when you're not having to wait for someone else to get something done. (That sounds like Amdahl's Law!)
I'm "invested" in the question, but it's a matter of _my own_ free time & energy.

Comment: Also, it may not be obvious to other users when I have enough information to give a complete & accurate answer. I suspect this because I've seen many questions that have enough information to answer, but they're older and closed. It's not worth my time to do anything about it, and that's really unfortunate.

Comment: @awwright It would be nice if you provide some clarification why you are absolutely unwilling to fix the question yourself since you know exactly what is asked.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Fixing the question does not re-open it.

Answer (score 15):

That's *exactly* why it should be closed.  If a question needs clarification, then the OP should clarify it.

Once it's clearer, it can be reopened - a closed question is not (typically) a permanent thing.

We also want to further discourage people from asking unclear questions.  If your answer is based on unclear information, then it will be less valuable for others coming to the site.

Comment: First, the interface does not suggest this—I would expect if the question can be "re-opened", then it would be _suspended_ until there's a clarification.
Second, many of the questions are perfectly answerable as-is, these do not need to be closed, but there's no clear process on how to re-open them without moderator help.

Comment: @awwright Seems like you are not familiar with how the site works & should read the help.

Comment: @philipxy I'd like to think I'm familiar with the help section; but if you have a specific reason you think I'm not, I welcome _constructive_ feedback.

Comment: @awwright Funny how the wording used to be "on hold" (for the first week?) which cover your first problem. That said, you *should* read the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions): *"Closed questions can also be nominated for reopening by a user with sufficient reputation. If enough community members agree, the question will be reopened and can accept answers."*

Comment: @Nick Sure, but that doesn't answer _this_ question; how do you answer a question once it's been clarified, or a question that needs no clarification & was mistakenly closed? I still have to get ahold of a moderator and it sucks every single time.

Comment: You don't have to get a mod's attention @awwright.  Closed questions are always thrown into the close question review queue, so someone's at least looking at it to see if it's worth reopening.

Comment: Is there some way to get _notified_ when a question is re-opened? Or do I have to somehow remember "oh time to check if that question I wanted to answer has been reopened..."
I don't think that's reasonable. The only solution I've found, for answering a question _in a timely fashion_, is contacting a moderator.

Comment: @awwright philipxy's feedback *was* constructive. You aren't familiar with a basic part of how the site works (question closure) and reading the help center documentation on it will make you familiar with that part.

Comment: @awwright Yes, you can favorite a question or follow any post (question or answer). The latter is probably better because you will get an email and site notification about changes. Favoriting it will only make it show up and be highlighted in your profile page under the Favorites section so you have to do more active hunting with that option.

Comment: @TylerH I can't find _anything_ in the Help about getting notified when a favorited question is re-opened. And it's kind of a difficult feature to test, of course. Do you have a link with more information?

Comment: @awwright TylerH said that favoriting does not do notifications ("Favoriting it will only make it show up and be highlighted in your profile page under the Favorites section")... While it would be nice if it is not the case... why do you expect help to provide opposite information?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Oops I meant to say "follow", sorry about that.

Comment: @awwright "follow" is couple *weeks* old feature... I'd not expect any documentation on it for some time (SE may even remove it, also I hope it stays). You may find some blog post or meta post announcing it with some details.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov last I checked following also doesn't show question closures/reopens, although I last tested that a few days after it came out. (Shameless plug of my [feature request asking for it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396754/question-close-updates-phase-1/396755#396755) (Well it requests closure notifications but it would be daft to notify closures and not reopens))

Comment: @Nick Looks like the case. Indeed I only see edit/comment/answer as notifications on followed questions. At very least one can see "edit" so they know question has a chance of re-opening.